# What happens when app returns to foreground after 30 seconds of background execution finished?

Tags: ios

If an application starts to perform some activity in the foreground, then it moves to the background and continues to execute for the 30 seconds that the OS lets it run for, but then within that 30 seconds it has not completed what it was doing.

Then what happens when the app next comes to the foreground? Does whatever processing it was in the middle of doing when the 30 seconds was up automatically get resumed at the point it got suspended by the OS when in the background and the 30 seconds finished?

(Similar question - suppose the app calls UIApplication.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval().
Then if the user moves the app to the background, it runs for 30 seconds then stops, then the OS runs it in the background due to setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval having been called, does it resume exactly what it was doing at the end of the 30 seconds?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not continue. It seems that the answers you are looking for can be found in this parts of the documentation (emphasis mine), depending on how you transfer tasks to the background :

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1623051-beginbackgroundtask

> Each call to this method must be balanced by a matching call to the endBackgroundTask(_:) method. Apps running background tasks have a finite amount of time in which to run them. (You can find out how much time is available using the backgroundTimeRemaining property.) If you do not call endBackgroundTask(_:) for each task before time expires, **the system kills the app**. If you provide a block object in the handler parameter, the system calls your handler before time expires to give you a chance to end the task.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623125-application

> When this method is called, your app has up to 30 seconds of wall-clock time to perform the download operation and call the specified completion handler block. In practice, your app should call the completion handler block as soon as possible after downloading the needed data. If you do not call the completion handler in time, **your app is terminated**.